# Rwd and slow compass

Tags: rwd-theme, scss, sass

Anybody try to use something instead compass for compiling sass in rwd theme? Compass is painfully slow!

Answer (score 1):

There are several Compass-only functions that are contained in the RWD Sass files. If you remove those functions, Sass compilation should work. You will also need to recreate the config.rb files in Sass config files, including the fallback (if you are using it).

A simple way to determine which Compass functions are being used would be to try to compile the Sass using Sass and then when Sass throws an error, review what function is causing it to error and then replace that with a Sass equivalent.

Off the top of my head, I know that there are a couple usages of `tint` and `shade` that you will need to replace.